# Fetch error Internal Server Error /swagger.json

Tags: node.js, swagger

i am using hapi-swagger in node project. Swagger using for api documentation. but getting error

```
Fetch error
Internal Server Error /swagger.json
```

code i am using for swagger is below

```
const server = Hapi.Server({
port: 40000,

routes: {
    files: {
        relativeTo: '/var/www/borger.ca/html/project_management'
    },
    cors: {
        origin: [
            'http://localhost:4200',
            'http://localhost:3000',
            'https://team.borger.ca',
            'https://borger.ca',
        ],
        additionalExposedHeaders: [
            'filename',
        ],
    },
},
})

server.decorate('server', 'config', { ...require('./src/env/environments') 
[process.env.NODE_ENV] })

// SERVER METHODS
const appMessageMethods = require('./src/methods/sendAppMessage')
const emailMethods = require('./src/methods/sendEmail')
 const genCertificateMethods = require('./src/methods/generateLearningCert')
  { name: 'generateLearningCert', method: genCertificateMethods.generateLearningCert },
{ name: 'sendAppMessage', method: appMessageMethods.sendMessage },
{ name: 'sendPersonalMessage', method: appMessageMethods.sendPersonalMessage },
{ name: 'sendEmail', method: emailMethods.sendEmail },
])

  // server registrations and start up
const init = async () => {
const swaggerOptions = {
    path: '/documentation',
    tags: {
        'foobar/test': 'Example foobar description'
      },
    info: {
      title: 'Example API',
      description: 'Powered by node, hapi, joi, and hapi-swagger',
      version: '1.0',
    },
  };
await server.register([
    require('@hapi/inert'),
    require('@hapi/vision'),
    {
        plugin: HapiSwagger,
        options: swaggerOptions,
    },
```

when i check in network tab i get error like

```
Could not load content for webpack://SwaggerUIBundle/node_modules/swagger-client/es/http/index.js (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)
```

i implemented every thing but getting an error  and not accessing my api's by using swagger.